# HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode (Unable to set memory on HAXM settings beyond 978 MB)

Tags: android, android-emulator, intel, haxm

```
emulator: device fd:17820
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1024 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 978 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
creating window 40 81 335 557
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

When i am trying to adjust the memory from **AVD manager** it adjusts as per my settings entered but on running the emulator system resets the memory of emulator to `1GB`

If i try to adjust memory from `HAXM` it doesn't allow memory setting above `798MB`

Answer (score 0):

You can't set more than 768MB for HAXM. See [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) → Tips and Tricks,

> - When creating the image it is not recommended to set the “Device ram size” larger than 768 MB.